# what mean the "E: Unmet dependencies"

Tags: installation

I was tried  to install the "prozilla" but ,i was cancel the 
installing while process is run.so now here,below error is occurred ,when i try to install any software.that's mean i can't install any software ,because this.Does anyone know what mean this error and how can i solve this case.thanks

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-proz : Depends: prozilla but it is not going to be installed
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libept1.4.12 (>= 1.0.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Try reading following link, maybe can help you
http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies
sMl

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Have you tried running this command in terminal? This should help.

Comment: yes ,but not any different